# Cloudbees: App Engine Deployment failing

Tags: google-app-engine, cloudbees

Strange error when deploying to GAE from Cloudbees DEV@cloud Jenkins instances:

```
[cloudbees-deployer] Deploying as stuart.langridge@PROJECTNAME.com to Google App Engine
[cloudbees-deployer] Deploying PROJECTNAME
[cloudbees-deployer]   Resolved from workspace as /scratch/jenkins/workspace/PROJECTNAME/PROJECTNAME
ERROR: Couldn't find path for tool 'GAE Python SDK 1.7 (latest)' 
com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.exceptions.DeployException: No {0} SDK available for node.
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.impl.google.PythonEngineImpl$DeployActorImpl.<init>(PythonEngineImpl.java:224)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.impl.google.PythonEngineImpl.newDeployActor(PythonEngineImpl.java:62)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.impl.google.PythonEngineImpl.newDeployActor(PythonEngineImpl.java:44)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.engines.Engine.process(Engine.java:159)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.engines.Engine.perform(Engine.java:100)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.DeployBuilder.perform(DeployBuilder.java:85)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:791)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:572)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1665)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:246)
Build step 'Deploy applications' marked build as failure
Recording test results
```

Now, this used to work. I install node as part of my test scripts, so Jenkins can use casperjs and phantom to run the test suite. However, the app itself doesn't use node (it's Python, on Google App Engine). The two relevant lines seem to be

```
ERROR: Couldn't find path for tool 'GAE Python SDK 1.7 (latest)' 
com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.exceptions.DeployException: No {0} SDK available for node.
```

and I do not understand what's looking for a path, or why there'd be an SDK needed for node. (I think that "node" there does not mean "nodejs"; I think it means "this node that Jenkins is running on; i.e., a computer".)

So, why can't the deployer find an SDK? More importantly, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppEngine SDK 1.7 isn't supported anymore, and has been removed from build slaves. Change your jenkins instance configuration to use the 1.8 SDK

Comment: I did that but got another error
com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.exceptions.DeployException: remote file operation failed: /scratch/jenkins/workspace/PROJECT/PROJECT at hudson.remoting.Channel@25891d0a:fb8fa364
...
Caused by: hudson.util.IOException2: remote file operation failed: /scratch/jenkins/workspace/PROJECT/PROJECT at hudson.remoting.Channel@25891d0a:fb8fa364
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/scratch/hudson/pythons/python-2.7.2/bin/python" (in directory "/scratch/jenkins/workspace/PROJECT"): error=2, No such file or directory
Is that an entirely different problem?

Comment: I think I'll accept your answer and raise the question as a new question.

Comment: New question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21792187/cloudbees-app-engine-deployment-failing-with-gae-sdk-v1-8 raised.